# SQL Server Analysis question- my cube breaks, claims it can't find a column that is there

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas, olap

I'm trying to learn SSAS on my own and am having troubles understanding a problem with my cube.  I have a database project where I want to do reporting on a single table.  I know this a bit unusual, but its a relatively simple model and data has already been normalized into that one table.  It has two columns that serve as dimensions- time of auction end and product type.  There are a number of measures, including # of items sold and sell price.  After I set up the cube and dimensions in SSAS and process it works fine, and I am able to browse the cube.  I can browse the cube from SAS or from a SSRS report I've made.

However, if I come back on a later day I cannot update the cube anymore.  The table's schema supporting the cube has not changed, though there are new rows.  When I 'process cube' within SSAS, I get this error:

> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found: Table: dbo_ScrapedAuction, Column: Id, Value: 76878. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The record was skipped because the attribute key was not found. Attribute: Id of Dimension: Scraped Auction from Database: SSAS, Cube: Ebay Scraper, Measure Group: Scraped Auction, Partition: Scraped Auction, Record: 2913. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The process operation ended because the number of errors encountered during processing reached the defined limit of allowable errors for the operation. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the 'Scraped Auction' partition of the 'Scraped Auction' measure group for the 'Ebay Scraper' cube from the SSAS database.

There is definately a table [dbo].[ScrapedAuction], it does still have the [Id] column, and there is a row in the table I can query with Id 76878.  Does anyone have any ideas what issue I'm running into?  I work around this by recreating the cube... which is not a real solution for production systems.